# Which File was run after ng-serve. in angular or version angular 12

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am working in Angular 12 and i am newly in angular after working in the projects i am thinking that which file was
start or serve after fire the ng-serve command in cmd or terminal. and how to change the look of the cli.

I am expecting that cli are looking diffrent in the cmd or terminal.